# How to get a speicifc element from unknown number of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a mathematica function that returns a list of the form:

```
list1 = {
            {
                {a11,a12,a13},{a21,a22,a23},...
            },
            {
                {b11,b12,b13},{b21,b22,b23},...
            },
            ...
        }
```

And I want to create three lists of the form

```
newlist1 = {
               {a11,a21,...},
               {b11,b21,...},
               ...
           }

newlist2 = {
                 {a12,a22,...},
                 {b12,b22,...},
                 ...
           }


newlist3 = {
                 {a13,a23,...},
                 {b13,b23,...},
                 ...
           }
```

Comment: Either of `Transpose[]` or `Flatten[]` can do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = {{{a11, a12, a13}, {a21, a22, a23}}, {{b11, b12, b13}, {b21, b22, b23}}}    

{newlist10, newlist20, newlist30} = Transpose[list1, {2, 3, 1}]
newlist10 // Grid
newlist20 // Grid
newlist30 // Grid
```

> {{{a11, b11}, {a21, b21}}, {{a12, b12}, {a22, b22}}, {{a13,     b13},
>   {a23, b23}}}

[image]